# How to correctly implement nth-of-type here?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="Main">
    <div id="sub">
        <section id="sub2">
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </section> 
    </div>
</div>
```

When I am trying "div:nth-of-type(1)before{content: "Foo: ";}" the Foo is being outputted on the all the divs. I understand why this is happening. Is there a way to workout around this and only output for the div under section?

Edit: I can't do nth of section because I face the same problem. There are other places I have the section element too.

Comment: `section div:nth-of-type(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## sub2 should be unique, so:

```
#sub2 div:first-child::before{content: "Foo: ";}
```

Comment: replace section for #sub2

Comment: Perfect! That's was what I was missing. How to uniquely identify the element. Waiting to accept the answer!